# How to remove only the title of console in a C program?

Tags: c++, c, windows, console, title

How can I remove only the title of the console in C or C++?

Remove that:

[image]

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow(); 
DWORD style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~WS_THICKFRAME;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't do that reliably. The console host window is owned by the system. If you need your custom console host, you're going to have to write one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [`SetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta), like this:

```
SetWindowText( GetConsoleWindow(), TEXT("") );
```

This will set the title of the window to an empty string.

If you want to remove the entire title bar, then you can use the following code:

```
DWORD style = GetWindowLong( GetConsoleWindow(), GWL_STYLE );
style &= ~WS_CAPTION;
SetWindowLong( GetConsoleWindow(), GWL_STYLE, style );
```

However, moving the window will be a lot harder without a title bar.

Comment: You really should not be manipulating the console window at all, since you are not the one who owns it to begin with.  If you want a custom UI, make your own window.